# Flutter firebase realtime db to use displayName in Rules

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I updateProfile with a display name. I then try to access this display name in the database security rules. But the displayName on the database is not updated.

This is using Firebase realtime DB with Flutter.

Code:

```
await referencedData.firebaseAuth.currentUser.updateProfile(
        displayName: 'gameName'       //that only the players know about
    );
```

In my rules I have:

```
".write": "!data.exists() ||

auth.displayName == data.child('gamename').val()",
```

//rules meaning no data exists, so owner can create a new game or

//game name already set in database, I know this gamename, and it is in display name, so I can write and delete

I have spent 3 days or more searching for documentation or examples. Any ideas on where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All properties are available under `auth.token`, and the display name is available under `auth.token.name`.

So:

```
".write": "!data.exists() ||
            auth.token.name == data.child('gamename').val()",
```

Also see the Firebase reference [documentation for `auth.token`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#authtoken).

Comment: I tried to get at setting a value in token, but I could  not work out how. I see a ...currentUser.RefreshToken. I had assumed token is something in Firestore, rather than realtime DB

Comment: The syntax and link in my answer for Realtime Database rules. The display name is available in the `name` property, as also shown in my answer.

Comment: I think my problem is getting the gamename into ...currentUser.token presumably with something like    displayName : "gamename"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your code sets the display name of the user profile, which shows up as `auth.token.name` in the security rules. Is that not the happening for you?

Comment: Sorry, I just don't appear to understand what you are saying. I can generally use the Rules, and a work around is shown below using the rules.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't appear to understand what you are saying. I can generally use the Rules, and a work around is shown below using the rules. I cannot set, in Flutter, a name value, displayName value, nor can I find anything on setting Tokens. I can find lots of information on Token Streams, but I don't think that is what is needed. My work around is for the Game owner to place the UID into the starting node. (I understand this is not ideal as any hacker then gets at the most powerful UID). Then for each player to update data , I have to ensure the gameName is somewhere in the updated data

Comment: I think what is happening: even though I set displayName, the previous displayName is stored in currentUser. When I hard-code the previous gameName the rules (sometimes) work.

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying Derek. Sorry about that. All I can say, is what I said in my answer. When you update the `displayName` in the user's profile, that name will (after up to an hour) be available in the `auth.token.name` in your security rules.

Comment: You answered my problem with the  ~one hour, to be available in auth.token.name. When setting up a game, that would not be quick enough. Another solution is to store the owner and maybe player, UIDs. I think I read that it is not ideal to place UIDs in the DB. For updates, I can always put in the 6-character gamename in the update, and have a rule for data.child('gamename').val() ==newData.child('gamename').val(). For delete, I think I will have to have the owner UID in the DB. It may be that I could have something like the last 6 characters of the UID, and maybe a rules with contains.

Comment: If you want the rules to get the updated token faster, you can force the client to get a fresh ID token right after updating the profile: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/getIdToken.html

Comment: Thanks! now works

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you very much!!!! I wasted whole day searching for a fix why is auth.token.name null but this fixed it. Horrible docs by google